# downscale large 1 bit tiff to 8 bit grayscale / 24 bit

Tags: tiff, libtiff

Let's say i have a 100000x100000 1 bit (K channel) tiff with a dpi of 2000 and i want to downscale this to a dpi of 200. My resulting image would be 10000x10000 image. Does this mean that every 10 bits in the 1 bit image correspond to 1 pixel in the new image? By the way, i am using libtiff and reading the 1 bit tiff with tiffreadscanline. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That means every 100 bits in the 1 bit image correspond to 1 pixel in the new image. You'd need to average the value over 10x10 1bit pixel area. For smoother greyscales, you'd better average over *n* bits where *n* is the bit depth of your target pixel, overlying the calculated area partially with neighbor areas (16x16px squares 10x10px apart, so their borders overlay, for a smooth 8-bit grayscale.)

Comment: Keep in mind, though, that this blurs the image in addition to downsampling.

Comment: With 1.3px blur radius the effect will probably add to (subjective) quality rather than reduce it, and I found upscaling from 100 to 256 grayscale levels by a simple lookup looks really ugly in gradient areas of the image.

Comment: I just tried my own experiment with both a 5x5 and 7x7 averaging blur, followed by a 5:1 downsample. The one with the 7x7 blur was much nicer than the other. I'm not sure I would base the factor on the bit depth of the target though.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand why you want to downscale (because of output medium or because of file size?). As SF pointed out, colors/grayscale are somewhat interchangeable with resolution. If it is only about file size losless/lossy compression is also worth to look at..

The other thing is to understand a bit of the characteristics of your source image. For instance, if the source image is rasterized (as for newspaper images) you may get akward patterns because the dot-matrix is messed up. I have once tried to restore an old news-paper image, and I found it a lot of work. I ended up converting it to gray scale first before enhancing the image.

I suggest to experiment a bit with [VIPS](http://www.vips.ecs.soton.ac.uk) or Irfanview to find the best results (i.e. what is the effect of a certain resampling algorithm on your image quality). The reason for these programs (over i.e. Photoshop) is that you can experiment with GUI/command line while being aware of name/parameters of the algorithms behind it. With VIPS you can control most if not all parameters.

[Edit]
TiffDump (supplied with LibTiff binaries) is a valuable source of information. It will tell you about byte ordering etc. What I did was to start with a known image. For instance, [LibTIFF.NET](http://www.bitmiracle.com/libtiff/) comes with many test images, including b&w (some with 0=black, some with 1=black). [/Edit]

Comment: Actually my current problem now is interpreting bits in the 1-bit image.say i have  200x144 pix 1 bit image and i just want to convert it to a 200x144 pix 8 bit image,whereas my mapping would be 1-bit's 0 is 255 (gray) and 1-bit's 1 is 0 (gray). 
on a 1-bit image tiffreadscanline i get the following bits:
0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x00
i only get 25 bits but the 1-bit image's width is 200. so i expect a scan line size of 200 also.if i multiply 25 by 8 i get 200 but where would i get data? thanks.

Comment: You get 25 bytes 8 bits each for a total of 200 bits=pixels.
By increasing the depth to 8bit you will waste 7 bits in a byte of the resulting image.
It's up to you (using bit shift, masks and logical operators) to extract a single bit from the byte.

Comment: I agree with SF. Please see my [Edit] in my post.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks!!

I managed to extract the bits by using & operator (2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128) in each byte. So now I can convert, 1 bit to a non 1 bit format. Now I am doing the downscaling of the large 1 bit tiff (100,000 X 80,000) @ 2400 DPI. The only reason I want to downscale this to a 200 DPI non 1 bit format is to be able to read the image with C# GDI+.

Comment: Use a libtiff derivate... GDI+ TIFF handling is horrible in Windows XP. Windows 7 seems to do a much better job. From C#.NET you see a mysterious error on XP whereas the Windows7 call will work as expected.